# Does missing DB icon in phpmyadmin equal broken database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have migrated my wordpress site to a new host and new base, but the site isn't loading. I am suspecting that it might be a database issue, and have noticed that the usual db icon in phpmyadmin is missing.

Is that a clear sign it is broken, and what could I do to fix it?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Did you read [Moving a wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Why the `mariaDB` tag if you are using MySQL

Comment: Which icon is missing?

Comment: Site is not loading? Did you check the error logs for useful clues?

Comment: Did the domain name change for the new host?

Comment: Do you mean that the database-icon, in the top left column is missing from the tree-view? If so, it's because you've already navigated in to that 'into' the database, (funkii_dk)

Comment: Yes, I followed that, and went through it many times @RiggsFolly. I have exported from mysql 5.7 with 4.0 compatibility, since I am importing to a mariadb base. Hence the tag. The domain changed, from our own testserver to clients production. I figured out the issue in this case though - Something as simple as I had forgotten to select which database to import into, in phpmyadmin. For more than 10 hours.. Thanks for all the comments.